# df linux command used in c++ returning wrong value

Tags: c++, linux

I'm using a c++ code onto a Linux system.
In my code, I'm currently using the `mount()` function (with `#include <sys/mount.h>`) to mount my SD card called `"mmcblk1p1"` in `dev. --> /dev/mmcblk1p1` is my SD card.
I can mount successfully, write things onto it, unmount it using `umount()` c++ function. All good so far.

Now, I want to know what is the free space before doing any writing onto it.
To do so, I'm using this Linux terminal command in my algo:

```
FILE *stream = popen("df /dev/mmcblk1p1", "r");
```

I'm able to get the stream output, and pick up the desired value.

**My problem is:**
If I proceed manually in command line (no c++ algo..), I can mount my SD card, use the `df` command, and get the following response:

```
 Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mmcblk1p1   7555072 124544   7430528   2% /mnt/usb
```

The value 7430528 is definitely correct and this is the one I want by the way.
BUT, if I proceed using my c++ prog, I get something like that:

```
 Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
 devtmpfs          328668     4    328664   1% /dev
```

It seems that, for some reason, when my SD card is mounted by my algo, the response given by the OS after using `df` command is wrong, and does not concern the SD card at all. In my algo I'm getting the successfully the value 328664, but unfortunately that does not correspond to my SD card.

If any idea, thanks a lot for helping.

Regards

Comment: Are you sure mount has been completed when you send the df ? maybe you need to wait a little to see the device mounted.

Comment: The output shows you are trying to `df` two different things. You shouldn't be using this method anyway, use `statfs(2)`.

Comment: @ Macro: yes I've tried to leave a delay before using df function. That did not change anything...

Comment: @ n.m: that is the weird thing ! The system is reporting info concerning devtmpfs, but the function in my algo is definitely pointing mmcblk1p1, which is the device name for my sd card...........

Comment: Just tried statfs(2). I believe that vfs.f_bsize * vfs.f_bavail should give me the available free space on my SD card. And........surprisingly, I get the value 328664.................feel really confused now